# Writing to csv file with python, only writes first few elements then ellipsis

Tags: python, csv, nltk

I am trying to write lists of lists of strings to a .csv file, and for some reason, it only does the first few elements than an ellipsis (the way printing is sometimes formatted). I'm not sure if it has to do with the `nltk.corpus.reader` or the `CHILDESCorpusReader`, or if there's some way to edit the way I write things to the file. Below is the code and a screenshot out of the file itself. Thanks so much for any ideas!

```
import os
import os.path
import nltk
import csv
from nltk.corpus.reader import CHILDESCorpusReader
corpus_root = nltk.data.find('/Users/home/Desktop/Childes')

with open('child_speech_test.csv', 'w') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

    thewriter.writerow(['Child\'s Age', 'Child speech'])

    for root, directory, files in os.walk('/Users/home/Desktop/Childes'):
        for f in files:

            ffile = os.path.splitext(f)
            if ffile[1] == '.xml':

                path = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, f))
                path = '/Users/home/' + path

                filename = CHILDESCorpusReader(corpus_root, path)

                corpus_participants = filename.participants(path)

                corpus_participants_string = str(corpus_participants)

                age_string = re.search('(?<=\'age\': \').\w+', corpus_participants_string)


                if age_string is not None:
                    age = age_string.group()
                    child_speech = filename.sents(path, speaker=['CHI'])
                    thewriter.writerow([age, child_speech])

                else:
                    print('Not there')
```

[image: CSV output]

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 10)
```

```
>>> pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 10)
>>> pd.DataFrame(index=[i for i in range(10)], data={'foo':[['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'that', 'is', 'very', 'long'] for i in range(10)]})
         foo
0  [this,...
1  [this,...
2  [this,...
3  [this,...
4  [this,...
5  [this,...
6  [this,...
7  [this,...
8  [this,...
9  [this,...
```

Comment: On second look, I'm afraid this isn't the answer.  Having the input data would be helpful.

Comment: Ah, comments won't let me add screenshots. But basically, the input is coming from an xml file, and CHILDESCorpusReader is a way of reading this particular kind of xml file. `filename.sents(path, speaker=['CHI'])` returns a list of lists, which each has strings of words

Comment: Without the input data (ie the xml file), and pip installing the dependencies, running the program is tough.  Did the pandas set_options() do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to do the pandas set_options(). Would I just run this code before the code I have above? Or would I have to integrate it? What would I do if wanted to have no upper limit?

Comment: Yeah, pandas.set_options() should be called prior to doing anything that would cause the dataframe to render itself for display.  Having a runnable sample would help, but that would require a sample of input data, etc.  So you are left to exclude the things that cause python data structures to pretty print and so forth.